# No output error when attempting to display json

Tags: javascript, json

When the following code executes it's showing no output. Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong?

**html file:**

```
<head>
<script type = "text/javascript">function ajax_get_json()

    {
    var hr = new XMLHTTPRequest();
    hr.open("GET","mylist.json",true);
    hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type :application/json",true);

    hr.onread


    ystatechange = function()
    {
    if(hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200)
    {
    var data = JSON.parse(hr.responseText);
    var results=document.getElementById("results");
    results.innerHTML = data.user;

    }
    }
    hr.send(null);
    results.innerHTML = "requesting...";
    } 

</script> 
</head>

<body>

    <div id="results"></div>
    <script type = "text/javascript">ajax_get_json();</script>

</body>
```

**json file:**
{ "user":"John", "age":22, "country":"US" }

Comment: Did you check the (error) output at the browser's debug console? What does it say?

Comment: do a `console.log(hr.responseText)` and `console.log(data);` and see what the values are

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*XMLHTTPRequest()* must be `XMLHttpRequest()`. The JavaScript file looks like:

```
function request() {}

request();
```

HTML

```
<script src="file.js"></script>
```

With `var data = JSON.parse(hr.responseText);` you have on **object**.
Go through the object:

```
for(var key in obj) {}
```

and **store** key and obj[key] in **innerHTML** to see a result.
Complete JavaScript file:

```
function request() {
  var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  hr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {
      var data = JSON.parse(hr.responseText); // object
      var results = document.getElementById("results");
      results.innerHTML = "";
      for(var key in data) {
        results.innerHTML += key + " " + data[key] + "<br>";
      }

    }
  }
  hr.open("GET", "mylist.json", true);
  hr.send();
  results.innerHTML = "requesting...";
}

request();
```

(Please change the title of your question. Be specific!
[How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask))